# Emotion word density

Tags: text, nlp, statistics, analytics

I am currently working on a feature that gives the count of words for different emotions present in the text using a lexicon in python.Is there a possible to way to create emotion word density from the count of words?

Answer (score 0):

It's relatively simple to do standard word counts with python - or more easily using a package, spacy, sklearn, etc.

In standard python, it would look like this:

```
sentence = 'This is stackoverflow, the word stackoverflow should appear twice.'
# Split on space.
wordlist = sentence.split()

freq = []
for w in wordlist:
    freq.append(wordlist.count(w))

print("Pairs\n" + str(list(zip(wordlist, freq))))
```

A more advanced approach would be to look at using [TF-IDF vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf), which helps deal with frequent, but less important words appearing. Sklearn has an implementation of [this as well as word-frequency counts](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction).

Without knowing your dataset and its structure more, my sense is that you're more looking at Sentiment analysis. In which case, hopefully you'll have labels for your dataset and possibly follow similar steps as described in [NLTK's documentation](http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html) as a start.

I don't have the points to comment, hence the general answer and not a comment sorry!